# Return a max date from a range of dates but only if all cells contain a date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to get a formula that will give me a max date only if all cells have a date in them.
If one cell contains a blank value or N/C I do not want the formula to populate a date in column R.

I have tried `=max(C7:Q7)` but this populates even though there is a blank or not complete within the range.

I have tried to use ISBLANK and IF / NOT but this is not working for me.

[image]

Comment: try this: `=if(COUNT(C7:Q7)=15,max(C7:Q7),"")`